# Parsing JSON array and object in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, parsing

I don't understand how to parse an object through an array

This is what the JSON looks like:

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"username":"DNS","email":"1111111@gmail.com"},{"id":2,"username":"ANT","email":"22222222@gmail.com"}]}
```

Java:

```
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           super.onPostExecute(s);
           try {
               JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
               for (int i = 0  ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   Log.e("jsonobject",object.getString("username"));
                   textView.setText(object.getString("username"));
               }

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can create a `JSONObject` first using a json string and then a `JSONArray` object.

Then iterate over this array and manipulate with nested objects.

```
String jsonStr = "{\"users\":[{\"id\":1,\"username\":\"DNS\",\"email\":\"1111111@gmail.com\"},{\"id\":2,\"username\":\"ANT\",\"email\":\"22222222@gmail.com\"}]}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
int length = jsonArray.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
     System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("id"));
     System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("username"));
     System.out.println(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).get("email"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I redid it like this and it worked:

```
@Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
           super.onPostExecute(s);
           try {
               JSONObject users = new JSONObject(s);
               for (int i = 0; i < users.getJSONArray("users").length() ; i++) {
                   JSONObject user = users.getJSONArray("users").getJSONObject(i);


                   Log.e("jsonobject",user.getString("id"));
                   Log.e("jsonobject",user.getString("username"));
                   Log.e("jsonobject",user.getString("email"));

                   textView.setText(user.getString("username"));
               }
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
```